# IE 8 Compatibility Mode Causes Form Submit Button to Wrap

Tags: html, css, forms, button, compatibility-mode

The below code does what I want in browsers I check with except IE when using compatibility mode.

In compatibility mode the submit (<kbd>Remove</kbd>) button wraps to the next line. It should look like it does in Firefox or IE when not using compatibility mode.

Can't use `float:left/right` because I cannot specify length beforehand.

```html
<div>
  <ul style="display:inline-table">
    <li style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap">
      <div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; width:100%"><b>Name: </b>Test Name That is Longer Than The Other <b>Qty: </b>1</div>
        <div style="display:table-cell">
          <form style="margin:0; padding:0" name="remcart" method="post" action="page_name.html">
            <input name="Quantity" value="0" type="hidden" />
            <input style="margin:0; padding:0; margin-left:5px" type="submit" value="Remove" name="rembutton" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap">
      <div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; width:100%"><b>Name: </b>Short Test Name <b>Qty: </b>1</div>
        <div style="display:table-cell">
          <form style="margin:0; padding:0" name="remcart" method="post" action="page_name.html">
            <input name="Quantity" value="0" type="hidden" />
            <input style="margin:0; padding:0; margin-left:5px" type="submit" value="Remove" name="rembutton" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    form {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>

<ul style="display:inline-table">
    <li style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap">
        <div>
            <span><b>Name: </b>Test Name That is Longer Than The Other <b>Qty: </b>1</span>
            <form style="margin:0; padding:0" name="remcart" method="post" action="page_name.html">
            <input name="Quantity" value="0" type="hidden" />
            <input style="margin:0; padding:0; margin-left:5px" type="submit" value="Remove" name="rembutton" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap">
        <div>
            <span><b>Name: </b>Test Name That is Longer Than The Other <b>Qty: </b>1</span>
            <form style="margin:0; padding:0" name="remcart" method="post" action="page_name.html">
            <input name="Quantity" value="0" type="hidden" />
            <input style="margin:0; padding:0; margin-left:5px" type="submit" value="Remove" name="rembutton" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Your solution works in that the buttons no longer wrap, but I forgot to add that I want the Submit (remove) buttons to line up on the right.  Otherwise, I would have just floated everything left.  Sorry this is such a pain.